# Which arduino will be suitable with bill acceptor

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-due

I want to connect a bill acceptor (protocol ID003) and 3 switches and an Ethernet shield to Arduino. I am building a system that accepts bill and pass on the information to our software. Which Arduino will be the best choice, we need something which will have lot of code and also communication should be fast.

1. ARDUINO MEGA 2560 REV3
2. ARDUINO DUE
3. Arduino Uno REV3

**--Edit--**

This is I want to create:

A bill acceptor connected with arduino. Arduino has 3 buttons. (1. Play button, 2. redeem cash button. 3rd is not necessary).

When user login on machine, I get the details of user account through an API.

When user inserts money in bill acceptor, it enables the play button and add money in users account (If user already has money in account, button will be enabled). User can play until his account is not empty (i.e. if user has 200 in account, he can play 10 times). User can earn or lose money.

I have to send this transaction detail through an API.
If user press redeem button, it will print a slip of account details (Total money in account)

**I am using Python.**

I need to know which arduino is suitable for this, Ethernet shield compatible with that arduino (I think I am going to use **ARDUINO MEGA 2560 REV3**, but I don’t know Ethernet shield compatible with this model).

Also I need some Idea how can I make this. This is first time I am using arduino and bill acceptor.

Comment: A "lot of code" isn't very specific; it's pretty hard to advise which board has enough memory. Same with "communication should be fast". Can you put any numbers to those? The Uno has about 28K of code space (at the assembly language level); it may be possible to translate that - very roughly - into lines of C++. They've shown serial speeds of 2M baud. On the other hand, a Mega isn't that expensive, has much more memory but probably similar serial capability. More details can get you a better answer.

Comment: Hi @JRobert, thanks for comment. I have edited question. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Is your board talking to Python on a PC or other device? Or do you mean to run Python on the Arduino board? If the latter, I expect you'll need more than an Uno. I use AtTinys, and Unos but keep one Mega available by for just this kind of project, where I don't know yet what resources I'll need. The Mega always has more than enough (for me, so far :), so I can get my project working right away, and decide later whether to port it to a smaller MCU.

Answer (score 1):

- Define 'lot of code', the Arduino Uno has 32 KB Flash, the Mega 256 KB.
- Define 'fast', the Uno/Mega are 16 MHz, the Due 48 MHz
- Three switches use 3 GPIO's, shouldn't be a problem on neither of them; the Mega has more GPIOs than the Uno, but both have plenty for your needs.
- The Ethernet shield are available for all three
- I don't know the 'bill acceptor', add a datasheet.

Conclusion: it depends on what is lot of code, and what is fast.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, I have edited question. Can you suggest something?